# Почему в массив stream заносится undefined,

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1];
var XOR_RESULT;
var stream = [0];
console.log("Inital array:"+arr);
    for (var i = 0;i < arr.length; i ++){
        XOR_RESULT = arr[0] ^ arr[5] ^ arr[7];
        arr.unshift(XOR_RESULT);

        stream.unshift(arr[length-1]);

        arr.pop();

        console.log(XOR_RESULT);
        console.log(arr);
        console.log(stream);
        }
```

мне нужно, чтобы в массив `stream` записывался последний бит из массива `arr`, и потом этот же последний бит нужно удалить из `arr`.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы в массив stream записывался последний  бит из массива arr , и потом этот же последний бит нужно удалить из arr

Comment: `stream.unshift(arr[length-1])` нету такой переменной `length`, может `arr.length`

Comment: замени `arr[length-1]` на `arr.pop()`

Comment: @uber42 действительно ! моя невнимательность , все работает ! =) спасибо вам огромное